# Loading angular2 library using systemJs

Tags: angular, systemjs

I was following the Angular2 quickstart guide from angular.io
They utilize systemJs for app loading.

angular2, rx.js and angular2.dev.js are loaded via script reference instead of importing ..

Is there anyway to import these scripts ?

```
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Including the Angular2 bundles directly registers its packages using the `System.register` method.

That said you can also configure SystemJS to load Angular2 files by files for each modules using the following configuration but it's less efficient:

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script>
  System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    map: {
      angular2: 'node_modules/angular2/src',
      rxjs: 'node_modules/rxjs'
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        format: 'register'
      },
      angular2: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
      }
    }
  });
  (...)
</script>
```

In both cases, it's possible to import corresponding modules (`angular2/*`, `rxjs/*`) in your application.

Comment: Why aren't you loading angular's polyfills from `node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.min.js`?

Comment: Thanks very much @CosminAbabei for pointing this out! You're completely right. I updated my answer accordingly...

Comment: This solution fails with the following error  "system.src.js:1085 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/src/platform/browser.js "  what i noticed is that there is no browser.js file in the platform folder

Comment: Sorry it's `angular2: 'node_modules/angular2'` instead of `angular2: 'node_modules/angular2/src'`